# Trying to convert string date into a date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat May 01 00:00:00 EDT 2010"

I am trying to parse this date using the SimpleDateFormat class.

```
java.util.Date prevStartDate = new Date();
java.util.Date prevStopDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
prevStartDate = dateFormat.format(startDateLY);
```

Comment: The date you're trying to parse looks nothing like your date format you've shown us.  In fact, I don't see a call to `parse` in your question at all.  Is that the relevant code?

Answer (score 3):

That would be because you're using the format of `yyyy-MM-dd` - you have to add each parameter in your input to that format.

It looks like your format is `E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`

So you need to convert from one to the other:

```
static DateFormat extended = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
static DateFormat simple = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String reformat(String extendedString) {
    Date yourDate = extended.parse(extendedString);
    String simpleString = simple.format(yourDate);
    return simpleString;
}
```

Or alternatively,

```
String reformat(String dateString) {
    return simple.format(extended.parse(dateString));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse("Sat May 01 00:00:00 EDT 2010");
String string = new String(date.getYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDay());
```

Should work better then just `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: i need the yyyy-mm-dd for a mysql insert

Comment: @kbrin8 - I've updated the answer to give you a string in that format

Comment: A couple issues with this. First, it uses a formatter for parsing (good) but why not also use a formatter for output as well? Second, using `new String` is almost always a poor decision, and indeed it is in this case as well as it forces a copy of the backing array.

Comment: @glowcoder yep, your solution is better, I've been doing c++ all day so my skills came out a bit rusty.

Answer (score 1):

SimpleDateFormat is Locale dependent, so by providing one you can get the Date string localized for specific language or country

http://www.javablogging.com/java-simpledateformat-examples/