# String to Date parse java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want to parse a string  `Thu Apr 03 07:53:53 BST 2014` to a Date object in java. I don't know how to handle the 'BST' part - i have tried this

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

but getting Unparseable date: "Thu Apr 03 07:53:53 BST 2014"

Comment: The string comes back with 'BST', guess i will do a str.replace("BST","") ?

Comment: You don't need to replace it. Just change your date format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to convert string date into a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568223/trying-to-convert-string-date-into-a-date)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `BST` part. Use `zzz` for it:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the date does not match the format string. The date has a timezone but the format string does not.

```
Thu Apr 03 07:53:53 BST 2014
E   MMM dd HH:mm:ss ??? yyyy
```

Adding timezone (`z`) to the format string solves your problem:

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
           .parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

Comment: That's an alternative, not a solution.

Comment: As Luiggi said. Unless you want to demonstrate how they would use this alternative, this would be better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one along with your locale using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29).

```
// Thu Apr 03 07:53:53 BST 2014
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse("Thu Apr 03 07:53:53 BST 2014");
```

Description of each pattern

```
EEE    -   Day name in week (in 3 chars)
MMM    -   Month in year (in 3 chars)
dd     -   Day in month (in 2 digits)
kk     -   Hour in day (1-24) (in 2 digits)
mm     -   Minute in hour (in 2 digits)
ss     -   Second in minute (in 2 digits)
z      -   Time zone (General time zone)
yyyy   -   Year (in 4 digits)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
       .parse(string)
```

Your time format doesn't match with the string. You missed the z in your format where it refers to the timezone. Check out this link for more details[SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)