# Set a date object in java from a string retaining the same format

Tags: java, date, cassandra, simpledateformat

I have an application where the data is read from the database. Database has a date column value stored in the format

```
Sat Oct 19 10:03:00 EDT 2013
```

Then I read database from my java code using getters and setters where the date column is

```
node.setHeadTime(Date newDate)
node.getHeadTime();
```

Hence Its a date object I get the date as

```
Sat Oct 19 19:33:00 IST 2013
```

Now I do some processing wherein I need to update the data and store it back to the database.

The data is changed to

```
Sat Oct 19 19:35:00 IST 2013
```

I need to store back this data to the database as

```
Sat Oct 19 10:05:00 EDT 2013
```

I tried the following code:

```
DateFormat edtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        TimeZone edt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        edtFormat.setTimeZone(edt);
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy"); // The timezone 'z' identifier was missing, I have added that now.
        Date dd1 = df.parse(headDate); //headdate is the date having string Sat Oct 19 19:35:00 IST 2013

String hd=edtFormat.format(dd1);
log.info("date "+hd);
        fnFillDetails(String hd);
```

this prints Sat Oct 19 10:05:00 EDT 2013 successfully.

But my issue is 
After I change the format I am sending it to a function

```
fnFillDetails(String hd){

node.setheaddate(hd); // But this obviously has an error as type mismatch of Date and String. 
}
```

I tried all possible workarounds none worked. I cannot change the datatype of the headdate to String.

How do I fix this issue? I need to retain the format and change it back to orignal format in the database.

Comment: "Database has a date column value stored in the format" - why isn't the value stored *as a date value*? Which database is this? Are you *sure* you're not just seeing the result of `Date.toString()`? (You need to differentiate between whatever text you might see when debugging, and how the data is actually being stored/retrieved.)

Comment: Dates don't have any format. Neither Java dates, nor database dates. Just use ResultSet.getTimestamp() / PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(), without trying to transform the dates to string.

Comment: If you cannot change the datatype of headdate, then pass Date to fnFillDetails.

Comment: No the date column is of type text. Using Cassandra database. Yeah  i am sure.  My problem is I need to set node.setheaddate(Date) //here. But my right result is in a String. I want to maintan the same result of String but convert it to Date object

Comment: @faheemfarhan : If i pass Date in my case dd1 : I get the result in a wrong timezone. I need it in EDT only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to convert string date into a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568223/trying-to-convert-string-date-into-a-date)

Answer (score 0):

```
        String headDate = "Sat Oct 19 19:35:00 IST 2013";

        DateFormat edtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        TimeZone edt = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York");
        edtFormat.setTimeZone(edt);

        DateFormat istFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
        TimeZone ist = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata");
        istFormat.setTimeZone(ist);

        Date dd1 = istFormat.parse(headDate);
        String hd=edtFormat.format(dd1);
        System.out.println(hd);
```

So now if you want to pass edt format to fnFillDetails
then call

```
Date edtDate = edtFormat.parse(hd);
fnFillDetails(edtDate);
```